# Event when WinForm is moved behind other windows

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a popup menu which is displayed when the user minimizes the form. However, when a user clicks on a background program such as a document of MS Word my form is behind the document but not minimized or hidden. Therefore, I cannot control this. Is there an Event on VS which can be used?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? That's horrible user experience!

Comment: @GrantWinney it's vb.net

Comment: @Luaan the popup menu is over the clock (bottom right) and it's a requirement.

Comment: Ok, but why is it a requirement? What purpose is it supposed to serve for the user?

Comment: You are not *supposed to* control this: The Windows operating system has definite ideas how windows ought to behave. What you're trying to do will likely feel unusual, unexpected and just plain weird to whoever is using your program. I recommend you to reconsider and stay as close to Windows' default UI/UX behaviour as you can manage.

Comment: You might be looking for [Form.TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? "A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost) forms even if it is not the active or foreground form."

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yes, I do use the .topmost on the popup. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Form.Deactivate event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Description from MSDN:

```
Occurs when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Deactivate Event of a WinForm

```
Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate
'Your code Here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Form.Deactivate` event, it's called when the form loses focus.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx